# React Native keyboard disappears after each letter press

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a register page on react native where I want to make an onboarding register page so I have my TextInputs in a separate function to switch between the text input when you go to the next onboard screen. But when I press on an input and want to start typing I can get one press of on the keyboard before it goes down again.

I have tried moving my useEffect inside that function then the issue is solved but the other functions cannot get the values then.

```
//Content
export default function Register({ navigation }) {
  const [name, onNameChange] = useState("");

  //get current slide index point
  const [currentSlideIndex, setCurrentSlideIndex] = useState(0);
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  //update slides upon index
  const updateCurrentSlideIndex = (e) => {
    const contentOffsetX = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const currentIndex = Math.round(contentOffsetX / width);
    setCurrentSlideIndex(currentIndex);
  };

  //button function to go to next slide
  const goNextSlide = () => {
    const nextSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1;
    if (nextSlideIndex != slides.length) {
      const offset = nextSlideIndex * width;
      ref?.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset });
      setCurrentSlideIndex(nextSlideIndex);
    }
  };

  const RegInputs = () => {
    if (currentSlideIndex == 0) {
      return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior="position">
          <BlurView intensity={20} tint="light">
            <Text style={styles.label}>Name</Text>
            <TextInput
              value={name}
              onEndEditing={(text) => onNameChange(text)}
              style={styles.input}
              errorStyle={{ color: "red" }}
              errorMessage="Incorrect Username"
            />
          </BlurView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      );
    } else if (currentSlideIndex == 1) {
      return <View></View>;
    } else if (currentSlideIndex == 2) {
      return <View></View>;
    }
  };

  const handleRegisterPress = () => {
    Alert.alert("NAME: " + name);
  };

  const Slide = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
        <View style={{ width }}>
          <Image
            source={item.image}
            style={{
              width: imagewidth,
              height: imageHeight,
              resizeMode: "contain",
              alignSelf: "center",
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>{item.title}</Text>
        <RegInputs />
      </View>
    );
  };

  const Footer = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: height * 0.15, width, paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "center",
            marginTop: 20,
          }}
        >
          {slides.map((_, index) => (
            <View
              key={index}
              style={[
                styles.indicator,
                currentSlideIndex == index && {
                  backgroundColor: "white",
                  borderColor: "#68BF7B",
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  width: 16,
                  opacity: 1,
                },
              ]}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
          {currentSlideIndex == slides.length - 1 ? (
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleRegisterPress}>
                <View style={styles.nextbtn}>
                  <Text style={styles.nextbtnText}>Finish</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={goNextSlide}>
              <View style={styles.nextbtn}>
                <Text style={styles.nextbtnText}>Next</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Text style={styles.bodyreg}>Already have an account?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}>
              <Text style={styles.bodylinkreg}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Use `onChangeText` not `onEndEditing` as per [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input)

Comment: I used onChangeText before I tried onEndEditing and its the same result

Answer (score 0):

change the prop onEndEditing in TextInput to onChangeText, and reload the entire app

Comment: I have done that and the issue still persist

Comment: I had the same problem before: when I enter a text, it will immediately go down and will register only the first letter in the textinput. is this behavior the same as you?

Comment: What did you do to fix it?

Comment: you can input one letter then the keyboard goes down so you have to press on the input again to type another letter before it goes down again

Comment: yeah, it was a really frustrating bug, as textInput was a really simple and basic component. my setText state was outside of the component. try changing the place of 
const [name, onNameChange] = useState("") in your code.

Comment: I can move it to inside Reginputs but then when I swipe in the onboarding it doesn't save the text in the input and results in an [object Object] when submitting, where else can I move it to?

Comment: I have just tried the same code of your textinput and it works perfectly. try using directly onChangeText = { onNameChange}, or use the memo hook to avoid unnecessary rerender.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244876/discussion-between-pieter-venter-and-mehdi-khalfallah).